# Installation bug in laravel 5.4 (ErrorException in EventServiceProvider.php line 8)

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have an error in version 5.4 of laravel, I follow the installation process correctly and at the moment of running the server and entering localhost: 8000 the following error is displayed.

```
    ErrorException in EventServiceProvider.php line 8:
Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher $events) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot()
```

For the installation I am executing the command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog
```

The installation finishes without problems, but when starting the server and entering to the navigator it shows the error before being measured

```
php artisan serve
```

please your help. Thanks

Comment: Trying to reproduce here... Nothing wrong. During composer create-project what version was downloaded?

Comment: can't reproduce the error! first check the `php version` you have installed in your system then run `composer dumpautoload` then try again.

Comment: @gmsantos my laravel version is 5.4.11

Comment: @Atiqur My version of php is 7.0.10, I have done what you suggested and worked, thank you very much.